# How to store image as cookie?

Tags: codeigniter, session, caching, cookies, browser

Hello
I am working on [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) project.
And my question is that : Is it possible to store image as cookie ?? 
If yes then can please you provide me some documentation or examples on it?

Comment: you can set image link in cookie

Comment: Yep man, I have thought about that...But it is not the same which I want..Actualy I want the same functionality as cookie works with images....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie is a short piece ox text that is stored on the user's computer. Typically it will be no more than 4096 bytes (the lower limit specified by RFC2109). If you can compress and base64 encode an image into this then it might be possible to store an image, but it will be a small image indeed!

Comment: Is there any other way to store image on a users computer??
Do you have any other logic to do so ???

Comment: You could use the HTML5 file system, perhaps, or localStorage could hold smaller base64-encoded images. Both will require Javascript to manage your images. Your best route is probably to make sure your caching is done effectively and allow the browser to cache your images.

Comment: Thanks buddy,Thank you so much...But can you help one more time and give me some documentation link  to understand localStorage as I am totally blank in that...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle the situation,

> 1.Encode the image to string and store the string to a cookie, but the size limit is 4kb
>
> 2.Store the image link to a cookie, but it should either located in our server or the image must be in the internet for locating.
>
> 3.Use HTML5 to store images locally [HTML5 code example: Intelligently store Images in localStorage for faster page loads!](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_store_images_using_localstorage57?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried this but i think if you use codeigniter sessions - with a session database table - then you might be able to store the image in the session db table. when you use a session table, codeigniter only stores an ID in the users cookie. 
     http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html